# Copy activity becomes progressively slower with a small batch size setting

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

We have a simple copy ADF activity taking data from Azure SQL staging DB into Azure SQL data warehouse. Same environment but these are two different databases.
Because sometimes we have huge delta load, we have put in a batch size of 25000 records.
But we have observed that when we put in batch records, the copy activity becomes progressively slower. While the first batch rate is as high as 20 MB/s as iterations increase, the speed goes slower to few hundred bytes per second. 
I implore if anyone can provide any insight.

Some screenshots attached below for reference

When ADF has copied 1 million rows out of 3.18 million rows
[image: When ADF has copied 1 million rows out of 3 million rows]

When ADF had copied 1.425 million rows 
[image: When ADF had copied 1.425 million rows]

ADF at around 2 million rows mark 
[image]

ADF at around 2.8 million rows
[image]

ADF at 2.875 million rows
[image]

Comment: Probably would need to get into the details of the data structures. Maybe a supporting index could help?

Comment: Did you try this document [Copy activity performance and scalability guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance)?

Comment: @LeonYue everything that's relevant in here for SQL to SQL copy. This definitely is something with how ADF does batches. I increased my batch size to half million and the task completed in some hours